Any updates ways to block wildcard outgoing traffic to a domain?
Suppose I'm going to block a domain and its subdomains that I know it has.
I tried these ways, but none of them worked as expected or didn't work at all:

/etc/hosts.deny (I later figured out this files denies only the incoming traffic, which is not I'm looking for:

ALL : .domain.com
ALL: .cdnsub.com


Using this rule in iptables as said in this answer:

iptables -I INPUT 1 -m string --string "Host: domain.com" --algo bm -j DROP
iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -m string --string "Host: domain.com" --algo bm -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -m string --string "Host: domain.com" --algo bm -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT 1 -m string --string "Host: cdnsub.com" --algo bm -j DROP
iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -m string --string "Host: cdnsub.com" --algo bm -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -m string --string "Host: cdnsub.com" --algo bm -j DROP

But when I load the website, it still loads the website with no problem.
What I'm going to do
Suppose the website is domain.com. I use tcpdump -i eth0 | grep domain.com' at first to see the connections.
Then I run tcpdump -i eth0 to see if any other domains are related and loaded (since it's a mobile app, I'm not sure if using the web and developers console work as expected).
Now I know if I open domain.com in the mobile, it loads content from these URLs:
domain.com
geo1.subcdn.com
geo1.subcdn1.com

And if I change my IP address by using VPS, I see these URLs:
domain.com
geo3.subcdn.com
geo3.subcdn1.com

Are there any ways to block all outgoing traffic to a domain and all its subdomains with no DNS queries as in iptables?
The issue is I don't know how many subdomains subcdn or subcdn1 has, so I'm looking for a way to block all *.subcdn.com and *.subcdn1.com and also the main domains theirselves, like subcdn.com and subcdn1.com.
The OS version is CentOS 7.

I would personally install unbound have these blocked on a DNS level by returning a NX ... that would require to have localhost as your only resolver and block queries to external DNS servers as well. Look up pi-hole, it does something very similar.
With iptables you could try using a hex-string instead of string:
iptables -I INPUT 1 -m string --dport 53 --hex-string "domain|03|com" --algo bm -j DROP

With a CDN your attempt to block IPs will fail because most CDNs have 50 or more IPs to them, but the name query iptables issues when loading the IPs (it only happens ONCE, when the rule gets added) will most likely never see more than 8 reponses.

Thanks a lot, but I didn't understand what domain|03|com does exactly. I know a bit regex, but I cannot understand if it's domain or 03 or com, what does it mean exactly. Can you help if I'm wrong?

That will block DNS queries containing that name. The |03| comes about because the protocol modifies the name, it replaces the . with the number of characters in the last part of the query. @Saeed

I added more info to the answer. @Saeed

Thanks, so the above rule blocks both domain.com and www.domain.com and blog.domain.com? Am I right?

It should, as it matches on the relevant substring, not the full name. Note that that blocks the DNS queries for said domains - if someone were to use the IP address they'd still be able to reach them. But as I said: with CDNs you'll have a hard time getting all the IPs you want to block from DNS in the first place @Saeed

It seems is not working. When I run I-tables -L | grep DROP, I see DROP       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             STRING match  "|796f757475626503636f6d|" ALGO name bm TO 65535 udp dpt:domain and also there's an entry for tcp. When I run curl -IL domain.com, I still can see the curl output.

How/why did you change 53 to 65535? @Saeed

That's the issue I think. I did not change any ports. I just added -p tcp and -p udp before --dport because of my iptables version

iptables -I INPUT 1 -m string -p tcp --dport 53 --hex-string "subcdn|03|com" --algo bm -j DROP and iptables -I INPUT 1 -m string -p udp --dport 53 --hex-string "subcdn|03|com" --algo bm -j DROP are what I ran

You need to repeat this for OUTPUT ...  @Saeed your rules would block incoming queries only.
